# TCP Flags not getting set with nmap Xmas scan

Tags: c, tcp, nmap

I am parsing the TCP Header on packets, and am trying to check if the flags are being shown correctly, however when running an xmas scan using the nmap command: nmap -sX localhost, no flags are getting set.

Here is the code I am using to check flags:

```
if(tcp_header->th_flags & TH_URG & TH_PUSH & TH_FIN)
    xmasScans++;
```

I am doing a similar process to check individual flags as well, just one by one.

Is the above code correct for checking flags?
Thanks

Comment: Just my $0.02: Play around with bitwise operators for a while, on a sheet of paper. Really get familiar with exactly what each one's effect on a binary number is. Then look up what `TH_URG`, `TH_PUSH`, etc. are (maybe even just by printing out their values in `main`), figure out what those are in binary, and work with them for a while to see what works.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not correct. Bitwise operators like `&` are left-associative, which means that you can treat it as though each operation is in parentheses from the left, like so:

```
(((tcp_header->th_flags & TH_URG) & TH_PUSH) & TH_FIN)
```

So imagine the flags were `0b00101001`, which is URG+PUSH+FIN and nothing else. The first operation is:

```
  00101001
& 00100000
= 00100000
```

So the result is simply `TH_URG`. Then the second operation is equivalent to `TH_URG & TH_PUSH`:

```
  00100000
& 00001000
= 00000000
```

So the result is `0`, false, and the conditional will always be false. Instead, you need to test each one separately and combine them with **logical** *and*:

```
if (tcp_header->th_flags & TH_URG
    && tcp_header->th_flags & TH_PUSH
    && tcp_header->th_flags & TH_FIN)
```